# Excel Conctenate Date with text

Tags: excel-2016

Need Help with syntax of including text and calculate the current year and previous month.

This is what I have so far:

```
='QWCF' &''& year(today) &''& datediff(month (today)-1)
```

Also need to determine the last day of the month for the previous month of current date.
thanks,

K

Comment: Do you have [excel-2016] paired with Office 365?

Comment: no desktop version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today is a function that needs (). It seems like you have a lot of extra quote marks that I took off. But does this get you what you want?

```
="QWCF"&YEAR(TODAY())&MONTH(TODAY())-1
```

If month must be two-digit, then you can stick a "0" at the beginning if the length of month is equal to 1. Like so,

```
="QWCF"&YEAR(TODAY())&IF(LEN(MONTH(TODAY())-1)=1,"0"&MONTH(TODAY())-1, MONTH(TODAY())-1)
```

Comment: Month needs to be 2 digit.

Comment: Thanks for the great assist.

Answer (score 0):

Use,

```
=TEXT(EOMONTH(TODAY(), -1), "QWCFyyyymm")
=TEXT(EOMONTH(TODAY(), -1), "QWCFyyyymmdd")
```

... or just use `=EOMONTH(TODAY(), -1)` in a cell and apply a custom number format of `QWCFyyyymm` or `QWCFyyyymmdd`.

Comment: =EDATE(TODAY(), -1) this gave me the date of 05/14/2016 and not 05/31/2016